# Disable item in CMFCToolBar

Tags: mfc, mdi, pack

I am trying to upgrade my MFC MDI application to use the new MFC Feature Pack.

I converted the CToolbar to CMFCToolBar. Now I am trying to disable one item in the toolbar under certain conditions. I listened to the ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI message of the item's ID and disabled the item by writing the following:

pCmdUI->Enable(FALSE);

This works perfectly only if the ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI message was handled in the CView object but not if handled in the CMFCToolbar derived class.

If there a way to disable an item from the toolbar class itself?

Answer (score 0):

The Toolbar is not part of the command routing in MFC. So it will never get the command and update command UI messages. You can see the command routing in detail here: [MFC Command Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shfzay75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You could overwrite the OnCmdMsg() method in one of the objects which gets the command messages (as you can see in the link above) and pass the message on to the Toolbar.